# Get-Acl specify no users just groups

Tags: powershell-4.0

I Was wondering how I can run `Get-Acl` so it only outputs only groups, e.g. "Accounts Dept" and not individual users such as "Bobby Joe", "John Doe", etc.

I want to get a list of shared folder mapped to the required groups only and don't want the output to have hundreds of end user names in the list.

Can that be done?

Comment: Sure. Build a list of groups and check if the identity references of an object are contained in that list.

Comment: Can you expand for me please.    Does that mean filter the output afterwards to remove all but the desired groups ?